# How to check the hash of other fields during authorization?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I will save all user **data** (**`name`, `email`, `password`, `phone`**) **with hashing** to database.

**Code from User model:**

```
public function setEmailAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['email'] = Helper::geted('e', $value);
}

public function getEmailAttribute($value)
{
    return Helper::geted('d', $value);
}
```

I have my own function for hashing in my `trait`. Where I can check hash other fields from database in **Laravel** on login process? I which file I can check hashes fields?

When I'll login with email given error `These credentials do not match our records.`:

[image]

For example, now I can send email on hashed view using my own function from input form, but this method not good. I can't find where in laravel checked password hash equals on sending login data for rewrite some rules to another my database fields: email, phone...

Comment: post your login controller

Comment: My LoginController not changed! You can see it [here](https://repl.it/@OtabiekMansurov/LaravelLoginController)

Comment: [Here](https://repl.it/@OtabiekMansurov/LaravelUserModel) also you can see my `User` eloquent

Comment: Where is checked default password hash comparision in Laravel?

Comment: you have to overide the method in logincontroller

Comment: How can I it overide? Can you show example with answer? @Adnan Mumtaz